# How would i make these images clickable?

Tags: html, image

here is my code

```html
  <div class="page-bottom">
   <div class="sidebar">
   
   </div>
   
   <div class="main">
    <div class="promo-tab">
     <div class="promo-image">
     
      <img class="image" src="IMAGES/bounty.png">
     </div>
     
     <div class="promo-string">Code</div>
    </div> 
    <div class="promo-tab">
     <div class="promo-image">
      <img class="image" src="IMAGES/brawl.png">
     </div>
     
     <div class="promo-string">Code</div>
    </div>
    <div class="promo-tab">
     <div class="promo-image">
      <img class="image" src="IMAGES/captainskin.png">
     </div>
     
     <div class="promo-string">Code</div>
    </div>
    <div class="promo-tab">
     <div class="promo-image">
      <img class="image" src="IMAGES/chefcases.png">
     </div>
```

I need to make the image clickable and go to a URL. also the Text. I used

```html
<img class="image" <a href="http://www.w3.org" src="IMAGES/bounty.png">
```

Not sure how to get it working. I can preview the webpage to show you if needed.

Comment: `<a ...><img ...></a>`

Answer (score 0):

To make a link in an image you add the `a` tag and the `img` tag and then close the `a` tag

```
    <div class="page-bottom">
        <div class="sidebar">

        </div>

    <div class="main">
        <div class="promo-tab">
            <div class="promo-image">
                <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">
                <img class="image" src="IMAGES/bounty.png">
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="promo-string">Code</div>
        </div>  
        <div class="promo-tab">
            <div class="promo-image">
                <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">
                <img class="image" src="IMAGES/brawl.png">
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="promo-string">Code</div>
        </div>
        <div class="promo-tab">
            <div class="promo-image">
                <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">
                <img class="image" src="IMAGES/captainskin.png">
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="promo-string">Code</div>
        </div>
        <div class="promo-tab">
            <div class="promo-image">
                <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">
                <img class="image" src="IMAGES/chefcases.png">
                </a>
            </div>
```

Comment: It works, however it makes my images move. There are 5 in a Row Next to each other, then it makes it go 2 in the first row, then they are all under each other creating tons of rows. Any fix to that?

Comment: @SupercellSupport  I edited my post,does your images have different sizes ?

Answer (score 0):

Using a anchor tag (`<a href="URL"><img src="IMG"></img></a>`)

```html
  <div class="page-bottom">
   <div class="sidebar">
   
   </div>
   
   <div class="main">
    <div class="promo-tab">
     <div class="promo-image">
     
      <a href="http://www.w3.org"><img class="image" src="IMAGES/bounty.png"></a>
     </div>
     
     <div class="promo-string">Code</div>
    </div> 
    <div class="promo-tab">
     <div class="promo-image">
      <a href="http://www.w3.org"><img class="image" src="IMAGES/brawl.png"></a>
     </div>
     
     <div class="promo-string">Code</div>
    </div>
    <div class="promo-tab">
     <div class="promo-image">
      <a href="http://www.w3.org"><img class="image" src="IMAGES/captainskin.png"></a>
     </div>
     
     <div class="promo-string">Code</div>
    </div>
    <div class="promo-tab">
     <div class="promo-image">
      <a href="http://www.w3.org"><img class="image" src="IMAGES/chefcases.png"></a>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases isn't possible to change the HTML structure (in your case is wrap the image in `a` tag to create the link). You can use javascript instead.

Change your `img` tag from this:

```
<img class="image" src="IMAGES/captainskin.png">
```

To this (just add an attribute):

```
<img class="image" src="IMAGES/captainskin.png" data-url="http://your-url-here.com/">
```

And use this simple jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
  $('img.image').click(function() {
    window.open( $(this).attr('data-url'), '_self' );
  });
});
```

When you click on an image with the class `image` you will be redirect to the URL on attribute `data-url`.

See the result in [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ba4eydy8/).